# Compilation issue with example code

Tags: java, compilation

example from the documentation, it compiles but I haven't managed to make it run.

> > >java -cp . SourceBee
> >
> > Error: Could not find or load main class SourceBee

I use following batch file:

```
@echo off
cd %1
echo Manifest-version: 1.0 > manifest.mf
echo Main-Class: %1 >> manifest.mf
javac %1.java
rem jar cvmf manifest.mf %1.jar %1.java
rem pause
rem java -jar %1.jar
java -cp . %1
cd ..
```

And this is the unmodified source:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SourceBee{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SourceBee");
        frame.setSize(800,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);

        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("User");
        userLabel.setBounds(10,10, 80, 25);
        panel.add(userLabel);

        JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
        userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
        panel.add(userText);

        JButton loginButton = new JButton("login");
        loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(loginButton);

        JButton registerButton = new JButton("register");
        registerButton.setBounds(180, 80, 80, 25);
        panel.add(registerButton);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Manifest must be in the META-INF directory

Comment: thank you, but when I dont make a jar with a manifest, I can still not run the class file